# An error occured, please run package manager from right-click menu

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, dependencies

I Just installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS today and after a few minutes, I had a red circle with a white minus inside of it at the top bar, I clicked it and this error message popped up:

```
An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was:' Error: Opening the cache (E: can not open /var/lib/apt/lists/ir.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu__dists__jammy-backports-InRelease-fopen (13: Permission denied), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies
```

Comment: Try sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f